# I'm trying to deploy nuxt app to google-cloud-platform but always fails on deploy?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, nuxt.js

I'm trying to deploy
my nuxt app to gcp following official nuxt docs, but i keep getting this error
[image]

I don't know exactly what to do?!!, please save me.

Comment: Your node.js version is a bit low. Try to use the 14 or at least the v12. And also try to build it locally!

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, the deployment failed due to your dependency:`fs-extra` which requires at least `nodejs` **v12** or **v14**. Like @kissu mentioned, you should upgrade your `nodejs` version. I assume that you are using **[App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs)**, by **default** the App Engine Flex always uses the **latest LTS version** of nodejs. And it seems you specified and use the lower version of nodejs.

To change the version of `nodejs`, edit the `package.json` file by using the engine field then redeploy, for example:

```js
{
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12"
  }
}
```

Comment: `fsevents` never made a build fail for me AFAIK (on Linux). There is maybe a warning or so but nothing blocking.

Comment: Thanks @kissu, I overlook the `fs-extra` I though it is also `fsevents`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: `>=12` could be a good idea too.

Comment: If you're not pinging the OP, he will not get the intel that you've sent something. I mean, he could have followed your answer but I doubt it.